# ¿Error en la respuesta externa?

Tags: angular5, http

quiero hacer una peticion a una URL externa.La respuesta que envia es un string separado por "|" Ejmple:"una| ves".
Codigo de mi del metodo de mi servicio:

```
    getDatosPersonaFromReniec(numerDni: string) {
    let nombreApellido;
    /*$.ajax({
      url: "http://aplicaciones007.jne.gob.pe/srop_publico/,
      crossOrigin:true,
      dataType:"jsonp",
      success: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })*/
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Content-type", "text/plain")

    this.http.get<string>("/srop_publico/Consulta/Afiliado/GetNombresCiudadano?DNI=" + numerDni + "", {responseType:'text'}).pipe(map(data => {
      return JSON.stringify(data)
    })).subscribe(da => console.log(da))

  }
```

pero me sale un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué te dice el error? Y aparte ¿no crees que te estás complicando la vida al pedir texto para luego trasnformarlo a un objeto? Angular ya hace todo eso por defecto

Comment: me sale que error de parse de json,lo que recibo no es un objeto,sino un texto,lo que me esta devoliviendo es un texto con un caracter "|" ahi viene el error